# Get database value from order details in Prestashop backoffice

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, prestashop

I have created a new field in ps_cart_product with the name obs. When the client add a product to cart and if the product meet some pre defined criteria the field obs from ps_cart_product will be updated with some additional information.

At this point all works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to receive the value of obs field from order details in backoffice with no sucess. I have printed the smarty array $products but I can not find the obs field. Where can I found the right db query so I can add the custom field?

Thanks for your time and colaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the "obs" column from the cart products, you would have to edit (or override) the Cart->getProducts() method in /classes/Cart.php.

This method contains a SQL query:

```
$sql->select('cp.`id_product_attribute`, cp.`id_product`, cp.`quantity` AS cart_quantity, cp.id_shop, pl.`name`, p.`is_virtual`, [...]
```

Simply adding "cp.obs," should do the job.

You may also want to check the getProducts() and getProductsDetail() in the Order class (/classes/order/Order.php).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I have edited the /classes/Cart.php and added
`LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'cart_product cp ON (cp.id_product = p.id_product AND ps.id_shop = od.id_shop)`
to getProductsDetail function. Now I can use the smarty array with obs data. One more question. Do you know where prestashop insert data into ps_order_detail table? I want also to add a custom field on this table. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yep, in /classes/PaymentModule.php, search for "// Insert new Order detail list using cart for the current order" in the validateOrder() method.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Your help have been very useful. Unfortunately I still can't find the query part.

Comment: It would be better to create a new separate question :-)